# Robotframework Write JSON to CSV

Tags: python, robotframework

i have 1 token and i want  write to file .csv

***This is the token that I got.***

[image]

with robotframework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [Create File](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html#Create%20File) for new file.

```
Create File    example_filename.csv    ${response}
```

Or [Append To File](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html#Append%20To%20File) for existing file.

```
Append To File    example_filename.csv    ${response}
```

Comment: I use keyword Create File  it's not work but Append To File it's work   , Thank you